# Is there a proof that the number of eigenstates is countable for a bound system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra, differential-equations

When you solve Schrödinger equation for a free particle with no boundary conditions your eigen states are indexed by quantum number $k \in \mathbb R $ and $\mathbb R$ isn't countable but if you add a harmonic oscillator potential, your eigen states are indexed by harmonic number $n \in \mathbb N$ which is countable.

More interestingly for the hydrogen atom, your potential is finite as it goes to $\infty$. So for $E>0$ you have an uncountable number of states but for $E<0$ there are only a countable number of eigenstates/values.

I can't think of any counter example but I have no idea how to go about proving the number of eigenstates for a general bound system is countable.

I find this interesting because if you ignore your ability to measure position and momentum it would appear that you can change the dimensionality of your system by changing your potential.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Schrodinger equation for the harmonic oscillator has an uncountable infinity of *solutions* but just countably infinite *normalizable* solutions.  (Come to think of it, the free particle solutions aren't normalizable either).

Comment: @AlfredCentauri There are uncountable many normalizable superpositions between just the two lowest energy states. I agree that there is a countable maximal orthonormal set within some Hilbert Space but it's not clear to me what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Timaeus, the point of your comment is unclear to me.

Comment: You can't measure position (that requires having access to equipment sensitive to arbitrarily large energies) and you can't measure momentum (that requires having equipment with access to arbitrarily large amounts of space). You can make interactions that are most sensitive to small regions of position space or most sensitive to small regions of momentum space. But keep in mind that it is the square integrable states that have a probabilistic interpretation and they live in a space with a countable maximal orthonormal set.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I thought the same about your comment but tried to point out possible errors. There literally are an uncountable number of normalizable states, so you probably meant to say something else. There are uncountably many angles and for each angle I can make $\cos(\theta)\left|0\right\rangle+\sin(\theta)\left|0\right\rangle$ which is of unit length. Just like $\mathbb R^2$ is uncountable even if you restrict to unit length vectors.

Comment: @Timaeus, surely the context is clear; here we're talking about eigensolutions to the TISE.  For the harmonic oscillator, there are uncountably infinite eigensolutions but only countably infinite solutions that are square integrable and thus represent physical eigenstates.  I don't see the relevance of your superposition observation.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri You just said "For the harmonic oscillator, there are uncountably infinite eigensolutions but only countably infinite solutions that are square integrable and thus represent physical eigenstates" so this time it is more clear you mean "For the harmonic oscillator, there are uncountably infinite eigensolutions but only countably infinite **eigen**solutions that are square integrable and thus represent physical eigenstates."

Comment: @AlfredCentauri And of course if you have a harmonic oscillator for a particle with nonzero spin then there all of a sudden are an uncountable number of normalizable energy eigenstates. Which is one of the reasons it was harder to figure out what you meant. Though now I think you've been clear that what you are restricting to a countable number is the eigenvalues that make it be normalizable.

Comment: [Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory)

Comment: I think the correct way to phrase the question would be something like, let $H = -(\hbar^2/2m) \nabla^2 + V(x)$, acting in a suitable rigged Hilbert space. When are there at most countably many negative eigenvalues of $H$?